# API returns valid JSON in code, but invalid JSON in browser

Tags: c#, json, api

I've got a very simply API method that looks like this:

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    Doors door = (Doors)Repository<Doors>.Get(id);
    string d = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(door);
    return d;
}
```

With this in the WebAPIConfig:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
    .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

When I put a breakpoint on `d`, I get this:

```
{"DoorSys":100000,"DoorName":"Door 1 - Out","DoorID":"Door # 01 (Out)","LocationSys":-1,"StatusSys":100001,"OrganizationSys":805408}
```

That's all good. But by the time it shows up in the browser, it looks like this:

```
"{\"DoorSys\":100000,\"DoorName\":\"Door 1 - Out\",\"DoorID\":\"Door # 01 (Out)\",\"LocationSys\":-1,\"StatusSys\":100001,\"OrganizationSys\":805408}"
```

And if I put what is returned in the browser into a JSON formatter, it of course doesn't like it.  At all.

What (if anything?) am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer by L.B, I am doing this instead:

```
public Doors Get(int id)
{
    Doors door = (Doors)Repository<Doors>.Get(id);
    return door;
}
```

That works!

Comment: Side note, shouldn't your response headers be for JSON not "text/html"?

Comment: Have you tried to declare your Get method as `public Doors Get(int id)`? You are double-serializing the *door* object

Comment: @scunliffe - maybe?  I found the "text/html" answer on another thread that asked the question, "How do I return JSON instead of XML".

Comment: Change it to "application/json".

Comment: @L.B That worked!!  Put that as an answer and I'll mark it as such

Comment: Let MVC do the serialization for you.  There's no need to do it yourself.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the post as answered.

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me @Kixoka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are double-serializing the *door* object. Declare your Get method as

```
public Doors Get(int id)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say he's double-serializing it, it just serializes once, then returns the serialization as a string.

Comment: @Dispersia then the underlying framework serializes that string again. This is the reason of *escaped* string